# To set the flag value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a flag which i set the value false. When user click on the sign off button then in need to the set the flag value true and on the body unload function no need to popup.

```
<body onbeforeunload="return refershFunction()" onunload="clearLogin(); return true;">
```

This will show the popup only in case of flag value false. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it ? What issue you faced ?

Comment: yes rayon i have set the flag = false and when i call the signof webservice in the response of that i change the value flag= true but now i don't know how can i implemented the condition under body tag if flag==false then call before unload like that

Comment: Bhai how does your code look like ? How will one know wht you have written ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **localstorage** of browser.

```
// Store a variable
 localStorage.setItem("is_logged_in", true);
// retrive variable 
var login_flag  = localStorage.getItem("is_logged_in");
// remove a variable from the localstorage 
localStorage.removeItem("is_logged_in");
```

Use the above code snippets as suitable to your logic.

**NOTE** : Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.
Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

*credit* : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp